# html5 tag <video> does not work in safari and IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, safari, webm

I have a webm video running on my site which is not working on safari and IE.

The code I have used is as

```
<video src="http://video.webmfiles.org/elephants-dream.webm" controls autoplay loop preload="auto" poster="http://my-site.com/images/home-banner.png" class="only-default" width="613" height="354">
   <source type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' src="http://video.webmfiles.org/elephants-dream.webm">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

WebM is not supported in IE and Safari

More info here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: @Hamid, I have added mp4 and ogg format video in source also but my safari browser does not support video tag.

Comment: <video width="613" height="354" poster="home-banner.png" autoplay loop>
   <source src="Video17021.webm" type="video/webm">
   <source src="Video17021.ogv" type="video/ogg">
   <source src="Video17021.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <p>You are seing this message as this browser can't display the video. Probably your browser doesn't support html5. Try upgrading or changing the browser.</p>
</video>

Answer (score 0):

Safari and IE9 require MPEG-4. You can include a second source tag for that.

You should remove the src= attribute inside your video tag when you use source tags.

If you need it to work on IE8 or lower, you can add a Flash player inside the video tag that will play the same mp4 file.

```
<video controls autoplay loop preload="auto" poster="http://my-site.com/images/home-banner.png" class="only-default" width="613" height="354">
  <source type='video/mp4;' src="video.mp4">
  <source type='video/webm;' src="video.webm">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks I have already included the mp4 as a second source and removed the src from video tag. In Safari I get the message "You are seing ..." please check my above comments for updated code.